# ¿Por qué aparece un espacio bajo un gráfico SVG que es el resultado de una medida de DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Estoy incluyendo unos gráficos SVG como resultado de una medida y no sé por qué razón además de mostrarme el gráfico SVG me incluye un espacio en blanco justo bajo la figura. He modificado diversos parámetros del SVG pero no he conseguido nada.

Os muestro imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código de mi medida:

```
Grafico = 
var _total=[Total]
var _inmediato=sum(Ventas[Valor])
var _ancho=ROUNDUP(_inmediato*100/_total,0)
return "data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='30' viewBox='0 0 100 30'>
<rect x='0' y='0' width='100' height='30' fill='grey'></rect>
<rect x='0' y='0' width='"&_ancho&"' height='30' fill='tomato'></rect>
<line x1='0' y1='0' x2='100' y2='0' stroke-width='2' stroke='black'></line>
<line x1='0' y1='30' x2='100' y2='30' stroke-width='2' stroke='black'></line>
<line x1='0' y1='0' x2='0' y2='30' stroke-width='2' stroke='black'></line>
<line x1='100' y1='0' x2='100' y2='30' stroke-width='2' stroke='black'></line>
</svg>"
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué aparece ese espacio bajo el gráfico SVG?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo conseguí

Publico respuesta por si a alguien se le presenta el mismo problema que a mí.

En esta pestaña de las propiedades del objeto visual tabla, modificamos el tamaño de Alto y Ancho, que por defecto viene de 75x75 y ¡¡listo!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad es que el resultado vale la pena.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]